# How to remove horizontal scroll and wrap everything in define width of bootstrap modal?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to hide horizontal scroll permanently and wrap everything in define width of modal window, so i used `overflor-x:hidden` that hides horizontal scroll but some of text is also hidden. How to wrap everything in `row` when you hide horizontal scroll in bootstrap modal window ?

main.html

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">Search Results</h3>
</div>
<div  class="modal-body app-modal-window-search">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th st-ratio="20">File Name</th>
                        <th st-ratio="80">Logged Message</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="item in showMessages" st-ratio="90">
                        <td st-ratio="20">{{item.filename}}</td>
                        <td st-ratio="80">{{item.value}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Close</button>
</div>
```

main.css

```
    .app-modal-window-search .modal-dialog {
        width: 1200px;
    }
.modal-body {
    max-height: calc(100vh - 210px);
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `max-height` to `min-height`

**Example snippet**

```css
 .app-modal-window-search .modal-dialog {
        width: 1200px;
    }
.modal-body {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 210px);
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    max-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn btn-sm login_stud del" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModa"> modal </a>
<div id="deleteModa" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                 <div class="modal-dialog">

                 <!-- Modal content-->
                 <div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">Search Results</h3>
</div>
<div  class="modal-body app-modal-window-search">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th st-ratio="20">File Name</th>
                        <th st-ratio="80">Logged Message</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="item in showMessages" st-ratio="90">
                        <td st-ratio="20">{{item.filename}}</td>
                        <td st-ratio="80">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Close</button>
</div>
</div>
</div></div>
```

Comment: i see your snippet is working but for some reason i changed `max-height` to `min-height` # 1 vertical scroll is not working with this change and # 2 text is still hidden from the right for `item.value`

Comment: add a `min-width;   ` according to your content width that would solve problem #2 and you don't see the scroll because your content height is less than the min-height.

Comment: # 1 i added `min-width:1200px` to `modal-body` class text is still hidden content `item.value` width is dynamic it is always changing

Comment: Updated my answer changed a few css..check if that helps

Answer (score 0):

can you try to put your model template inside the model content tag as below,

```
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Search Results</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body app-modal-window-search">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th st-ratio="20">File Name</th>
                            <th st-ratio="80">Logged Message</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="item in showMessages" st-ratio="90">
                            <td st-ratio="20">{{item.filename}}</td>
                            <td st-ratio="80">{{item.value}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
       <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i tried your solution but i still see hidden text on modal window

Comment: can you share the screenshot of your result screen?